# Какой шрифт штампа даты у фотоаппарата Canon IXUS 185

Tags: datetime, photoshop, шрифты, photo

Подскажите, какой шрифт штампа даты у фотоаппарата [Canon IXUS 185](https://www.canon.ru/cameras/ixus-185/specifications/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уточню, цифра ноль на шрифте выглядит чуть более квадратной, у единицы верхушка чуть меньше основания, двойка прогибается внизу, и семерка немного изогнута в основании (основание без утолщения), разделительные символы с отступом и по высоте шрифта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте шрифт Myhota по моему наиболее подходящий

Comment: Если нужно идеальное совпадение - оцифруйте шрифт по пикселям сами, это не так сложно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то что нашел ближайшие шрифты, выделения по размеру надписи, освальд более близко подходит, но сжата.

Comment: Подскажите где скачать первый шрифт? Или его название, а то это название модели фотоаппарата. Первый верхний шрифт очень похож, и по отступам до разделительного слеша, и по выгнутой семерки у основания, еще совпадает единица и ноль. Думаю это тот самый шрифт.